# Expected value of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-integrals

In the paper ["The Impact of Jumps in Volatility and Returns"](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/mjohannes/PDFpapers/EJP_JF.pdf) by Nicholas Polson, Bjorn Eraker, and Michael Johannes (2003), the authors state in footnote 6 on page 1273 that, given an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process of the form:
$$dv_t = k(\theta - v_t) dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t} dW_t$$
where $v_t$ is the process, k is the rate of mean reversion, $\theta$ is the long-run mean, and $\sigma$ is the volatility, we have that:

$$E[v_t] = E[v_0] + E \left[ \int_0^t k(\theta - v_u) du \right] + E \left[ \int_0^t \sigma \sqrt{v_u} dW_u \right]$$

from which they conclude that
$$\mu_v = \mu_v + k(\theta - \mu_v)t$$
where $μ_v$ is the expected value of $v$.

I am confused by this conclusion. I remember that the expected value of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is of the form

$$E[v_t] = v_0 e^{-kt} + \theta (1 - e^{-kt})$$
Even if we consider $v_0$ unknown, I do not see how the authors can conclude that $E[v_t]=\mu_v=E[v_0]$.

One possibility is that this is only true for $t$ close to $0$. In this case, the term $\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t k(\theta - v_u) du \right]$ will be small, and the expected value of $v_t$ will be approximately equal to the initial value $v_0$. However, this does not seem to be what the authors are claiming.

Another possibility is that the authors have made a mistake. This is certainly possible, as the footnote is only a few lines long and is not very well-explained.

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: That is the mean for the OU process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Mathematical_properties . However the process you wrote (or the one that appears in that paper) is not the standard OU process since $v_t$ appears in the diffusion coefficient. p.s I did not look at the paper since it is behind a paywall.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are right, that's not the standard OU process. However, the expected value is still $E[v_t]=v_0{e^{-kt}}+\theta(1-e^{-kt})$. I edited my question and now you can see the original paper, also [here](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/mjohannes/PDFpapers/EJP_JF.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The access to this paper is restricted so I cannot check if you quote these
authors correctly. There is however no reason to assume that the Journal of Finance has printed that nonsensical equation $\mu_v = \mu_v + k(\theta - \mu_v)t\,.$ It should be
$$
d\mu_v = k(\theta - \mu_v)\,dt
$$
which has the solution that you remember:
$$
\mu_v(t)=\mu_v(0)e^{-kt}+\theta(1-e^{-kt})\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for you reply, you can find the paper available [here](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/mjohannes/PDFpapers/EJP_JF.pdf), my issue is in footnote 6 p.1273

Comment: To be fair, the authors are explaining how to get the expected value of stochastic volatility with jumps, but the last term is not a issue; that's why I asked for the first three terms to the right of the equation.

Comment: @RobertoPalermo . I see. If I was the referee of that paper I would have asked to change that footnote. Their $\bar{V}$ can be reconciled with the long term limit ($t\to\infty$) of $\mu_v(t)$ in the presence of a jump term.

Comment: Right, but if we suppose that $\bar{V}$  is the long term limit, why they also state that $E[V_0]=\bar{V}$? This is what I'm having trouble with. 
A reason could be that they are supposing $V_0=\bar{V}$, but in the article they never state that.

Comment: I could not see where they state that. BTW a paper of that sort should be read not footnote by footnote. They aim for empirical results and we know how to calculate the expectation of an OU process, don't we?

Comment: Sure, but I'm using this paper for my MSc thesis and I should justify everything I state; the proof for the mean too.